# Is it bad design for your model obects to implement a behavior(interface)?

Tags: java, oop, model

Sorry if my question is really trivial. But I dont think I am good at 'designing', so wanted some insight on the topic

Say I have an empty interface Fruit, having different java implementations like Apple, Mango, Orange, etc.

I have a `FruitBasket` that has setter for all kinds of fruits i.e

```
basket.setApple(Apple a);
basket.setOrange(Orange o);
```

and so on.

Now, when I need to set a particular fruit for the basket, I need to invoke the correct setter. One way of doing it is to have a Utility service that will iterate through all te model objects(fruits) and invoke the corresponding setter on the basket.

Something like this.

```
public class FruitUtilty
{

 public static void setAllFruits(FruitBasket basket, List<Fruits> fruits)
  {
    for(Fruit fruit : fruits)
     {
        if(fruit.getClass() == Apple.class)
        {
            basket.setApple((Apple)fruit);
        }
        else if(fruit.getClass() == Mango.class)
        {
            basket.setMango((Mango)fruit);
        }
        else if(fruit.getClass() == Orange.class)
        {
            basket.setOrange((Orange)fruit);
        }

     }
  }

}
```

But the problem I see here is ugly if/else ladder. Everytime we add a model object, this utility will have to be modified.

So, I proposed a design wherein the interface wont be empty but have a '*setBasket*' behavior for all the fruits to implement.
i.e.

```
public interface Fruit
{
   public void setBasket(FruitBasket b);
}
```

Now all fruits(that are supposed to be dumb model objects) implement this interface in this way.For eg. an *Apple* would be like this

```
public class Apple implements Fruit {
 ....
 ....
 ....
 public void setBasket(FruitBasket b) {
   b.setApple(this);
 }
}
```

Now we no longer need *FruitUtility* class and wherever that FruitUtility's setAllFruits was being invoked we can simply use sniplet like this

```
FruitBasket f =  new FruitBasket();
List<Fruit> fruits = getAllFruits();

for(Fruit fruit: fruits)
 {
     fruit.setBasket(f);
 }
 ........
 ........
```

My teamlead says its a very very bad design as I have 'diluted' the model object. Our model is supposed to be a 'dumb' object only to carry data. So we should stick with the Utility based approach or anything else but this one.

What is the correct/best way of doing things (at least in JAVA)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Showing the code for `FruitBasket` would help to make this question clearer, at least for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in this case Fruits should be "dumb". Today you add them to the basket, tomorrow you'll sell them in a store, in a week you'll mix them into a salad :)

If you add a 'setBasket' method to the Fruits interface, these two notions become coupled at the interface level, which is not good.
On the other hand if is not extensible as well as you've stated this.

I think the best approach (at least this is how I would solve this) is to introduce an another  abstraction like "action" which would denote the action that can be done to the fruit.

If we're talking about the basket, I think you can create a common interface and implement it for each kind of fruits.

Example:

```
public interface FruitBasketAdder {

     void addFruit(Fruit fruit, Basket basket);
}


public class AppleBasketAdder implements FruitBasketAdder {

     public void addFruit(Fruit fruit, Basket basket) {

          Apple apple = (Apple) fruit;
          basket.addApple(apple);
          ....
     }
}

public class OrangeBasketAdder implements FruitBasketAdder {
     public void addFruit(Fruit fruit, Basket) {

          Orange orange = (Orange) fruit;
          basket.addOrange(orange);
          ....
     }

}
```

Now you can produce a registry that would denote the strategy that can handle all kinds of fruits. Like this:

```
Map<Class<Fruit>>, FruitBasketAdder> registry = new HashMap<>();
registry.put(Orange.class, new OrangeBasketAdder());
registry.put(Apple.class, new AppleBasketAdder());
.....
```

And the final point is to use this registry. Say, you have a common method that accepts a list of "Fruits" as an argument and tries to add it to the basket just as you've stated in your example with "if". So you should find an assigned "BasketAdder" from the registry (assume, you have a reference to the registry accessible) and add the fruit to the basket by calling the relevant BasketAdder. Here you go:

```
public void addFruitsToTheBasket(List<Fruit> fruits, Basket basket) {

    for(Fruit fruit : fruits) {

        BasketAdder adder = registry.get(fruit.getClass());
        adder.addFruit(fruit, basket);

    }
}
```

This design is much better than "if" because it allows to dynamically add new kinds of fruits without breaking the interface.
Just create a BasketAdder, pass it to the registry and you're done, the main algorithm (traversal + adding to the basket) remains unchanged.

Mark

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I think your teamlead is raising a valid point there. You are moving functionality from `FruitBasket` into the `Fruit`s, but `Fruit`s should not even know about `FruitBasket`. What happens if you have a `FruitBag` and a `FruitBox` as well? Whenever you introduce such a class you would have to change *every* `Fruit` implementor.

The logic of using the correct setter function is `FruitBasked` internal and should remain there.

Now about the "best way". No *best* solution comes to my mind here. The differentiation between the types of fruits has to be done somewhere. The `if .. else` might not be the most beautiful solution but looks ok. It might be better though to use an `enum` and a `switch/case`. That way you get a compiler warning when you forget about one type.

Generally the whole `setApple` vs `setOrange` approach is the cause of the problem. That way there is no need for apples and oranges to implement `Fruit`. But there is no easy generally advisible way out of this. It always depends on the details.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the surrounding tool chain and/or development style, if you have a dumb data structure "model" or one implementing business logic - with numerous differentiations between these two extremes, so this question is not generally answerable. But the utility-class approach has one major drawback and that's separation of concerns, because looking at the fruit basket class, no one has a direct information how this fruit separation is implemented without checking which classes access the fruit basket so that in the worst case, someone is implementing the same algorithm somewhere else because he doesn't know about this one utility class.